# Using a Try Catch to process logic

Tags: c#, try-catch

The below method iterates through a Try-Catch until a valid object is returned by the statement `driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId))`. If the element it is searching for doesn't exist yet (i.e. if the page is still loading for example) then an exception is thrown.

```
public static IWebElement AwaitElementLoadById(IWebDriver driver, string elementId)
{
    bool result = false;

    while (!result)
    {
        try
        {
            return driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works fine and as expected, however I remember reading a while back that Try-Catch statements should not be used to process/drive logic and only used for the desired purpose of handling exceptions.

My question then is, is there a more acceptable way of processing this kind of scenario without using a Try Catch to actually drive the logic.

**Caveat**: I know that this could potentially cause an infinite loop. In my working example I have a timeout on this method but for the sake of simplicity I have excluded from this snippet.

Comment: Side note: don't catch *general* `Exception` exception, but specific `NoSuchElementException` one

Comment: `return driver.FindElements(By.Id(elementId)).FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: If driver code is your own code, then add TryFindElement returning boolean and result in out parameter (or make FindElement return null). If that is third party code and they don't provide api which doesn't throw exceptions - well, nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks Evk... FindElement is 3rd Party (Selenium) method so cant really change what it returns if no match is found. I have a feeling I will need to just use the above in grimace.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `result` variable? It will always be `false`.

Comment: Hi Klaus... Thats the whole point. It will stay false thus keeping the where clause going over and over until the call to FindElements finally returns a value - at which point the method is complete 'returning' its result.

Comment: As far as I can remember you can use `FindElements` instead, which will just return an empty list if nothing is found, instead of throwing an exception. I might be wrong, but try it out.

Comment: Sorry Dmitry... As per Michaels reply above I didn't notice you had suggested the alternative plural method...! I will take a look to see if this returns an empty/null result when nothing is found.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry and Michael... That worked perfectly! If using driver.FindElements() instead of driver.FindElement() we get a null response if nothing is found instead of an exception! If either of you wish to offer this as an answer I will mark it as such. In hind-sight my question should have been about that method rather than Try-Catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the below worked for me in the end:

```
    public static IWebElement AwaitElementLoadByPath(IWebDriver driver, string elementPath, int timoutDuration)
    {
        bool result = false;
        DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

        while ((!result) && (starttime.AddMilliseconds(timoutDuration) > DateTime.Now))
        {
            IWebElement returnValue = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(elementPath)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (returnValue != null)
            {
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```